# How to handle /_ah/bounce end point notification in App Engine application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I am receiving `/_ah/bounce` messages in my App Engine application. This is visible to me from the App Engine logs in the Administration console.

There seems to be a lack of documentation around that and some digging into the App Engine Source Code seems to indicate the presence of classes like `BounceNotification` and `BounceNotificationParser`, which have only got introduced in the latest SDK 1.7.4.

Can someone explain:

1. Is this /_ah/bounce endpoint invoked only when a particular email could not get delivered and has bounced.
2. What settings do I need in my appengine-web.xml and web.xml to trap this /_ah/bounce end point?
3. How do I extract information on the bounce notification from the incoming request using the BounceNotification classes

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I never used the GAE with Java, but couldn't you just add a route for the /_ah/bouce URL in web.xml and redirect it to your servlet?

Comment: I have added a route /_ah/bounce in the web.xml but it did get routed to my Servlet.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to get routed to your Servlet. Then you can use the `BounceNotificationParser` to parse the `HttpServletRequest` you get in your `HttpServlet`, in order to get a `BounceNotification` object you can use.

Comment: I agree with you. And I have written a Servlet that is mapped to /_ah/bounce and also wrapped the incoming request as you have told. But the issue is that it is not invoking my servlet. On the other hand, the logs containing /_ah/bounce keep on increasing.

Comment: Have you tried it on your developement server, manually triggering that URL? This is kind of a blind and hopeless guess but try adding an aditional backslash at the `/` end of the URL in web.xml.

Comment: Yes on my development server, i can manually trigger the URL. In fact I can manually trigger that URL even on the Live Instance. I have even put in a Servlet Filter to monitor each incoming request and just log the incoming URI. Even that is not getting invoke on the live instance but it still appears in the Logs. I noticed they are POST calls, so I am handling those too. But still no luck. Thanks for your suggestions, really helpful to check if I have not missed anything.

Comment: I dont know the java-version of gae, but in python you could enable several features using *builtins*. These can intercept urls before you have any chance to route them. If the java-version has something similar, try to remove them temporary.

Comment: Yes I did that but that did not address the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those bounce calls were unwittingly exposed to you in the past. Now we released the bounce feature officially, so that you should be able to parse the bounce messages (easy!). For more details, please see the following doc:

Receiving Bounce Notification ([Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/bounce)|[Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce))

Comment: Takashi - that is true. I did see them getting released recently with the new AppEngine release. Thanks.